# Allowing request to pass through nginx only if has a custom header or it is from a specific IP range

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure n NGINX server as a reverse proxy.
I need to setup a configuration to follow this logic:

Check if the request is coming from a a specific IP address range.
If yes then send it upstream and if No then check for a custom header, if the header is present then pass the request upstream and if no then drop/block the request.

Can someone guide in how the configuration file would look like for this please?